# How do I get xcode to run the code in GameScene.swift instead of GameScene.sks

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

How is it possible to get xcode to run the code inside of the GameScene.swift instead of GameScene.sks?

Comment: what is your problem in create sprite nodes exactly?

Comment: To create the scene otherwise than loading it from sks file, you should do what Mina said. Still, even if you load the scene from sks file, you would be able to add nodes programatically, eg in didMove(toView:) method or from within any custom method that has a reference to a scene, or in touch handling methods. So I dont get what is the issue here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is in `GameViewController`

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }

     view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

     view.showsFPS = true
     view.showsNodeCount = true
 }
```

you can change it by replacing with this code

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene
    view.presentScene(scene)

    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true
}
```

it will run the code in `GameScene.swift`instead of the code in `GameScene.sks`. so you can create the nodes by code.

Comment: Thank you very much Mina, I have finally managed to get xcode to run my GameScene.swift file! Thank you very much again.

Comment: I had the same issue. Starting a new project and choosing a name with a dash in it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Mina This doesn't work for me. The nodes I add in GameScene.swift don't show up when running the project, I just get a dark grey screen. Any idea on how to fix this?